# ActiveSupport.remove_constant - Exception NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm working on a Rails (2.3.4) application that's using MySQL spatial extensions, so I'm using the GeoRuby (1.3.4) and spatial_adapter (1.1.2) gems.

Ever since I started using GeoRuby's Point objects however, I'm running into trouble when ActiveSupport tries to remove constants after handling a request:

```
[ pid=18105 thr=67398490 file=utils.rb:176 time=2010-12-07 15:00:38.894 ]: *** Exception NameError in application (cannot remove Object::Geometry) (process 18105, thread #<Thread:0x808d6b4>):
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:603:in `remove_const'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:603:in `remove_constant'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:603:in `instance_eval'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:603:in `remove_constant'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:450:in `remove_unloadable_constants!'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:450:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:450:in `remove_unloadable_constants!'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `clear'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:64:in `cleanup_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:17:in `close'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:136:in `process_request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Eventually this is causing Apache to receive a SIGTERM (probably because it's exhausing threads or something), so the server occasionally can't respond to any requests.

One thing that's odd is 'Object::Geometry' - I would expect that to read 'GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Geometry' instead (I'm using a couple of GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point's, which is a subclass of Geometry).

I also noticed how, in ActiveSupport 3.0.0, the code for remove_constant is different from the version I'm working with. Does that update fix this problem and if so, does that require an update to Rails 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duck-tape fixed it by surrounding the offending code (the remove_constant method body) in active_support/dependencies.rb with a begin-rescue-end clause, to ignore the exception. I'm not sure if this has any negative side-effects, but at least it doesn't cause Apache to restart every now and then anymore.